# MVC Model: The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Tags: c#, variables, variable-assignment

I have an application that I inherited, but no original code. I have decompiled the assemblies using Reflector 9, and one of the resulting Models is stuck with the error in the title. Normally this sort of error is quite simple, but this time it is baffling me. The full code is below, and the error is with the line containing

```
  (((nullable2 = this.Variations) = nullable2.HasValue
```

Variations is a property defined 10 lines later in the code with

```
  public decimal? Variations { get; set; }
```

The full code for the function is:

```
 public decimal GMActual
    {
        get
        {
            decimal? nullable2;
            decimal? nullable3;
            decimal? pOValue = this.POValue;
            if ((pOValue.HasValue ? pOValue.GetValueOrDefault() : (((nullable2 = this.Variations) = nullable2.HasValue ? new decimal?(nullable2.GetValueOrDefault()) : ((decimal?) (nullable3 = null))).HasValue ? nullable2.GetValueOrDefault() : 0M)) == 0M)
            {
                return 0M;
            }
            pOValue = this.POValue;
            pOValue = this.MonthActual;
            pOValue = this.POValue;
            return (((pOValue.HasValue ? pOValue.GetValueOrDefault() : (((nullable2 = this.Variations) = nullable2.HasValue ? new decimal?(nullable2.GetValueOrDefault()) : ((decimal?) (nullable3 = null))).HasValue ? nullable2.GetValueOrDefault() : 0M)) - (pOValue.HasValue ? pOValue.GetValueOrDefault() : (((nullable2 = this.CostOnSage) = nullable2.HasValue ? new decimal?(nullable2.GetValueOrDefault()) : ((decimal?) (nullable3 = null))).HasValue ? nullable2.GetValueOrDefault() : 0M))) / (pOValue.HasValue ? pOValue.GetValueOrDefault() : (((nullable2 = this.Variations) = nullable2.HasValue ? new decimal?(nullable2.GetValueOrDefault()) : null).HasValue ? nullable2.GetValueOrDefault() : 0M)));
        }
    }
```

As far as I can see. I am assigning as decimal to a decimal. This is a straightforward assignment of a value, but, what am I missing?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Use `==` operator for comparison, and `=` for assignment

Comment: there are two lines containing `(((nullable2 = this.Variations) = nullable2.HasValue`. Is the error in the `if`, or the `return` line?

Comment: It is in both lines.

Comment: The code is obfuscated:try to reduce it: f.e. 'nullable3' is always null,so ' ((decimal?) (nullable3 = null))).HasValue' is false...

Comment: I did try and reduce it, but it resulted in a variable not defined error for Variations. That was a curious result as I can imagine it arising if there were a problem with the braces. but that didn't appear to be the case as no other property or method was affected, so I went back to the original with the error

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve with the code?

Are you meaning to check for equality? If so, then will need to replace the = with == in all of the occurrences in your return statements.

Answer (score 0):

this doesn't really make any sense to me : `(((nullable2 = this.Variations) = nullable2.HasValue`, and from what i can see here, this is the condition part for the if statement. What I guess you're trying to do is something more like this :

```
nullable2 = this.Variations
nullable2.HasValue ? ... //and the rest of the statement
```

or ar you trying to check if it's not null and equal to variations? Then this should work:

```
(nullable2 != null && nullable2 == this.Variations) ? ...//the rest of the statement.
```

Answer (score 0):

The decompiler seams to have messed up the code - try another one to check. How else do you want to know, that you 'fix' is the right one?

PS: Are you trying to steal that code? Its obfuscated: the original programmer seams not to want you to see that code  ;).

Comment: haha, That person left the building (about 2 years ago, taking all of the code, maybe? We don't know. All that was left was a load of compiled binaries for a load of web apps...) No documentation no colleagues newbie me at the company...

I have tried ilspy, telerik and finally Reflector. No code stealing involved, but always open to better ways :)